# webview goes blank after 6068 chars but scrolling

Tags: android, webview

I created a content contains 1 to 12773 numbers.
My webview shows end with 1435, but it is scrolling to bottom as blank.
is there are a limit on webview? 
Thanks a lot.

My Code: (Note: TextView is WebView)

```
                    String output = Functions.HTMLTemplate(newsArticle.text);
                textView.loadData(output, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
```

For this problem the **newsArticle.text.length()** is **65535**

String **output** contains:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">   
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></head>  

<body> 
<div class='content'><p>1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 18........................ 12769 12770 12771 12772 12773 </div></body> 

</html>

<style>
@font-face {  font-family: MyFont;  src: url('file:///android_asset/Roboto-Regular.tff')}body { font-family: MyFont; line-height: 150%; font-size: medium; text-align: justify;}
.content {
    padding:  1px 1px 1px 1px;
}.note-video-clip{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;}
.video_container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
}
img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto   !important;
}

</style>
```

[image: screen]

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is this HTML in the app or is it a webpage? I've loaded HTMLs with 43960 to 120,021 characters with no problems. Also, it would be good to see how you've done this, instead of just a screenshot

Comment: code added. thanks.